# Is there a need for project restrictions?

Tags: pm-software, project-management-style

I'm currently developing some project management software and I just wanted to ask few things.

1. Is it necessary to restrict other members from creating/editing/deleting tasks even if they're not the one who created it?
2. If the task assigned to other person, can the people complete the said task?

I'm new here and I hope I could get some of your advice which would help me complete this project. Thanks!

Please help, I'll wait for your answers..

Comment: Hi, welcome to PS:ME. You are going to need to be a bit more specific about your situation.  Is this a question about your current project, or the tool you are using to input tasks?  You also may want to break up your questions into separate postings.

Comment: Hello thanks for the response. I am currently developing a project management software for my thesis project.

Comment: Since this is for a thesis can I ask what problem you are trying to solve with your software? I ask because there are many established project management tools out there - Trello, JIRA, MS Project etc - all of which offer role-based access controls. Have you identified a problem with these systems that needs to be resolved?

Comment: Yes actually, I have some questions regarding this existing project management tools. The project management tool in which I referred my system with is the Basecamp and Producteev. However they don't have restrictions in creating/deleting/editing/completing the task, that the other member could create/delete/edit/complete the existing task even though he's not the one who created it. Why is that sir? Thank you so much for your response.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Is it necessary to restrict other members from
>   creating/editing/deleting tasks even if they're not the one who
>   created it?

**Yes, it is absolutely necessary and required** to implement such restrictions and permissions in the Project Management System. Generally, these things should be controlled via Role that has been assigned to the different members using that system e.g. only Project Manager or Team Lead should be allowed to Delete tasks and other issues from the system, this way he/she will know which data is being cleared from the system and why it is being cleared, else everyone will start deleting records.

In similar way creating tasks should also be permission based, else all team members will start creating his/her own tasks in his/her own way (without any guidelines and syntax being followed, Believe me I have faced this issue personally in my project where at the end of the day every Developer and QA has created task for logging his/her own effort and title of any of those tasks doesn't make sense).

**Scrum Master** (Team Lead) should create the tasks for Developers and QAs and other team members for the User Stories to be delivered in the planned sprint. In this case even if he makes a mistake and that mistake will be same in all created tasks then the reviewer will know that he needs to update X with Y+2 (just example).

Coming to edit part, it should again be permission based, if any team member assigned some tasks found some issues with the created tasks, then he should go back to creator and then ask him to update the same, else it will again lead to a mess in the management system.

See, the whole idea is Management system is used for managing small or big projects, tasks of the users, Bugs, Defects, Effort etc. **If management system is not designed in an intelligent way to manage itself than it will not be helpful in managing the projects.**

> If the task assigned to other person, can the people complete the said
>   task?

Yes, ofcourse. Ideally the assigned person should complete the task but if the other person has knowledge and time to do so, he should complete the task (which generally happens), **But only the assigned person should be allowed to change the status of the task to Complete or Closed.** In this way everyone and especially the management will know who has actually done that particular task. So for this you management system will have to follow the process of re-assign that task to actual person working on it and then, he will change its status to complete. So when report is pulled from the system, each task has its actual performer.

Comment: Hello thank you so much for this answer. I just have a few questions. What I've planned for the system is to create a Kanban Board(Open, On going and Completed). My question is what if a task that has been opened has no assignee yet, then who will be the one to complete or close that task? Thanks.

Comment: This answer is very helpful. Thank you so much!

Comment: Every Task should have assignee or your system should have a default assignee (like Project Manager role user should be default assignee). In this case even if manager or lead creates some tasks for future releases, then these tasks will not be assigned to any team member, as they will be with default assignee and no team member will get confused with such tasks, as it is not in their bucket yet. Once such tasks are finalized, PM can assign them to appropriate team member.

Comment: But don't assume that a PM will always take responsibility for assigning issues to team members. In Kanban (or at least in many implementations of Kanban) teams are often self-organising in the sense that a backlog will be provided and team members are free to work on whatever's top of that list once they become available. In effect, they're assigining issues to themselves.

Answer (score 2):

As with most PM questions, it's very contextual - the requirement of permissions largely depends on your team's self-discipline, level of process ownership and dev culture; simply mandating them as a PM or other "process owner" role often implies that the team cannot be trusted to manage their own process and needs to be heavily constrained externally.

Talk to your teams - do they need or want permissions?